# Does the Product Backlog just consists out of User Stories in Agile Development?

Tags: agile, scrum, user-story, product-backlog

As far as we know, the User Stories are the way a requirement is defined in bounded context with acceptance criteria. On the other hand, the Product Backlog enlists all requirements, *i.e.*, new feature, enhancements, and existing production issues.

This is not clear, if or if not, the Product Backlog just consists out of User Stories. So, the question here is as follows.

**Does the Product Backlog just consists out of User Stories in Agile Development?**

Comment: Did you try searching for this? See https://www.scrum.org/

Comment: Rumen sums it up. But perhaps you can explain more about what you see the difference to be?

Comment: You say "as far as we know"... How do you know that? What research have you done already in the topic? I say that because "the way a requirement is defined in bounded context with acceptance criteria" doesn't sound like a User Story to me. I think if you read more on the topic you question would be naturally answered.

Comment: Yes @GregBurghardt, thank for the link. Also, I updated the question so that you could understand my doubts.

Answer (score 3):

The product backlog is simply list of user stories.

Comment: If possible, please provide more description to your answer. For instance, you could give some examples. As well as, more information regarding the topic.

Comment: I think this answer pretty well covers the gist of the relationship, but I would like to add that a Product Backlog may contain stuff other than User Stories.

Comment: @EricKing Why? Can you give some examples? If they're requirements, they shouldn't go into the backlog until they're written as user stories. If they're not requirements, ignore them until they're framed as requirements... after which, see my first point.

Comment: @PeterK. A User Story is a particularly formatted type of requirement statement, written from the perspective of the User. There are many other ways to express a requirement that aren't written in the form of a User Story. A backlog can contain any of those requirements. That's all I mean.

Comment: Yes, as well as user stories, there might be research epics/spikes and technical tasks like repayment of technical debt.